# Delete all citations in a PDF for fluent reading

Tags: pdf-format

I was wondering, if one could delte all citations in a scientific paper to allow for faster reading of the later. Sometime I only want to quickly grasp the content and all the brackets and citations do hinder it.

Here is a typicall citation. (McGrady & Reynolds, 2013; Smith, 1990; Tettegah, 1996).

Hence as a first step, I would delete everything in the text that is within brackets.

Here is a open resarch paper where one can download the PDF: http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2158244017742689

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Kuba pdf = Import[ "file", "Plaintext"]; is to slow

Comment: Then probably MMA is not a right tool for that.